# How to solve problem conflicts with existing children?

Tags: go

I have paths:
GET /test
GET /{test}
when I run the code I get

> wildcard segment ':test' conflicts with existing children in path '/:test'
>   how to solve this problem in go?
>   code:

```
r := gin.Default()
r.GET("/test", test1)
r.GET("/:test", test2)
```

Comment: /test matches both /test and /:test. You can define one path, /:test, and route yourself in the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Way 1:

Different handler functions (i.e. test1, test2) in different paths.

```golang
router := gin.Default()

router.GET("/test1", func(c *gin.Context) {
        // test1
    })

router.GET("/test2", func(c *gin.Context) {
        // test2
    })
```

#### Way 2:

Use one handler function with  parameter in path.

```golang
router := gin.Default()

router.GET("/:test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        test := c.Param("test")
        if test == "test1" {
             // test1
        } else if test == "test2" {
             // test2
        }
    })
```